# OrderedDict performance (compared to deque)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, optimization

I've been trying to performance optimize a BFS implementation in Python and my original implementation was using deque to store the queue of nodes to expand and a dict to store the same nodes so that I would have efficient lookup to see if it is already open.

I attempted to optimize (simplicity and efficiency) by moving to an OrderedDict. However, this takes significantly more time. 400 sample searches done take 2 seconds with deque/dict and 3.5 seconds with just an OrderedDict.

My question is, if OrderedDict does the same functionality as the two original data structures, should it not at least be similar in performance? Or am I missing something here? Code examples below.

Using just an OrderedDict:

```
open_nodes = OrderedDict()
closed_nodes = {}
current = Node(start_position, None, 0)
open_nodes[current.position] = current

while open_nodes:
  current = open_nodes.popitem(False)[1]
  closed_nodes[current.position] = (current)

  if goal(current.position):
    return trace_path(current, open_nodes, closed_nodes)

  # Nodes bordering current
  for neighbor in self.environment.neighbors[current.position]:
    new_node = Node(neighbor, current, current.depth + 1)
    open_nodes[new_node.position] = new_node
```

Using both a deque and a dictionary:

```
open_queue = deque()
open_nodes = {}
closed_nodes = {}
current = Node(start_position, None, 0)
open_queue.append(current)
open_nodes[current.position] = current

while open_queue:
  current = open_queue.popleft()
  del open_nodes[current.position]
  closed_nodes[current.position] = (current)

  if goal_function(current.position):
    return trace_path(current, open_nodes, closed_nodes)

  # Nodes bordering current
  for neighbor in self.environment.neighbors[current.position]:
    new_node = Node(neighbor, current, current.depth + 1)
    open_queue.append(new_node)
    open_nodes[new_node.position] = new_node
```

Comment: `OrderedDict` is implemented in Python, while `dict` and `deque` are both implemented in C.  The combination of `deque` and `dict` doesn't allow to implement an `OrderedDict` with the same runtime guarantees that the current implementation gives.  For example deleting an item from an `OrderedDict` is amortised O(1), which would not be possible with an implementation based on `dict` and `deque`.  Well, if you are lucky, Raymond drops in and gives you an authorative answer. :)

Comment: If you're using python 2.7 and want to overcome the performance hit of the OrderedDict you can have a look at this project - https://github.com/shoyer/cyordereddict, a Cython implementation of the OrderedDict.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Both *deque* and *dict* are implemented in C and will run faster than *OrderedDict* which is implemented in pure Python.

The advantage of the *OrderedDict* is that it has O(1) getitem, setitem, and delitem just like regular dicts. This means that it scales very well, despite the slower pure python implementation.

Competing implementations using deques, lists, or binary trees usually forgo fast big-Oh times in one of those categories in order to get a speed or space benefit in another category.

**Update:**  Starting with Python 3.5, *OrderedDict()* now has a C implementation.  And though it hasn't been highly optimized like some of the other containers.  It should run *much* faster than the pure python implementation.   Then starting with Python 3.6, regular dictionaries has been ordered (though the ordering behavior is not yet guaranteed).  Those should run faster still :-)

Comment: Update: Python 3.5 has a C implementation of OrderedDict. https://bugs.python.org/issue16991

Comment: Hi Raymond, vote up for the excellent post. In the discussion you mentioned, it seems the conclusion is set/get/popitem are all `O(1)`. Do you have any official document from python mentioning they are of performance `O(1)`. I do not challenge your answer, I just want to read more info.

Comment: I'd like to point out that regular dictionaries should *not* be used for ordering, even if one knows that their program will only be used in CPython. For most developers, the speed benefits aren't worth the loss of backwards compatibility and the risk of future breaking changes.

Comment: Are OrderedDict.poplast() and OrderedDict.poplast(last=False) also O(1)? What is the underlying datastructure?

Comment: @wprins Internally, it uses a doubly-linked list augmented by a regular dictionary that can be find a given link directly from the key.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sven Marnach said, `OrderedDict` is implemented in Python, I want to add that it is implemented using `dict` and `list`.

`dict` in python is implemented as hashtable. I am not sure how `deque` is implemented, but documentation says that `deque` is optimized for quick adding or accessing first/last elements, so I guess that `deque` is implemented as linked-list.

I think when you do `pop` on OrderedDict, python does hashtable look-up which is slower compared to linked-list which has direct pointers to last and first elements. Adding an element to the end of linked-list is also faster compared with hash-table.

So primary cause why `OrderDict` in your example is slower, is because it is faster to access last element from linked-list, than to access any element using hash-table.

My thoughts are based on information from book Beautiful Code, it describes implementation details behind `dict`, however I do not know much details behind `list` and `deque`, this answer is just my intuition of how things work, so in case I am wrong, I really deserve down-votes for talking things which I am not sure about. Why I talk things on which I am not sure? -Because I want to test my intuition :)

Comment: `list` is *not* implemented as a hashtable. `dict` is.

Comment: The first word of the second paragraph probably should be `dict` instead of `list`.  And your guess about `deque` being a linked list is correct.  The basis for an `OrderedDict`, though, is, besides a `dict` of course, a pure-Python implementation of a linked list.  This couldn't be replaced by a `deque` because of limitations of `deque`'s interface.

Comment: Deques are implemented using linked clusters of elements.  This gives them some of the benefits of linked lists while retaining the cache locality benefits of short arrays.

Comment: I really meant dict in the second paragraph. Sorry. `list` is an array, it is also very fast, however pop works a little bit faster on deque than on list.