# Removing duplicates from a list of lists based on a comparison of an element of the inner lists

Tags: python

I have a large list of lists and need to remove duplicate elements based on specific criteria:

1. Uniqueness is determined by the first element of the lists.
2. Removal of duplicates is determined by comparing the value of the second element of the duplicate lists, namely keep the list with the lowest second element.

`[[1, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]`

All the above lists are considered duplicates since their first elements are equal. The third list needs to be kept since it's second element is the smallest. Note the actual list of lists has over 4 million elements, is double sorted and ordering needs to be preserved.

The list is first sorted based on the second element of the inner lists and in reverse (descending) order, followed by normal (ascending) order based on the first element:

```
sorted(sorted(the_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True), key=itemgetter(0))
```

An example of three duplicate lists in their actual ordering:

```
[...
[33554432, 50331647, 1695008306],
[33554432, 34603007, 1904606324],
[33554432, 33554687, 2208089473],
...]
```

The goal is to prepare the list for bisect searching. Can someone provide me with insight on how this might be achieved using Python?

Comment: What happens if both first and second elements are equal?

Comment: The first and second elements represent the start and end of a range respectively. All duplicates are either a superset or a subset of another range. There shouldn't be two or more duplicates whose first elements are equal and whose second elements are equal. There're individual sub-lists that have equal first and second elements however i.e. represent a range of 1, but they never appear twice since a specific range is always unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the elements using a dict, always keeping the sublist with the smaller second element:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 3], [2, 5, 6], [2, 1, 3]]
d = {}
for sub in l:
    k = sub[0]
    if k not in d or sub[1] < d[k][1]:
        d[k] = sub
```

Also you can pass two keys to sorted, you don't need to call sorted twice:

```
In [3]:  l = [[1,4,6,2],[2,2,4,6],[1,2,4,5]]
In [4]: sorted(l,key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
Out[4]: [[1, 4, 6, 2], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 2, 4, 6]]
```

If you wanted to maintain order in the dict as per *ordering needs to be preserved.*:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 3], [2, 5, 6], [2, 1, 3]]
d = OrderedDict()
for sub in l:
    k = sub[0]
    if k not in d or sub[1] < d[k][1]:
        d[sub[0]] = sub
```

But not sure how that fits as you are sorting the data after so you will lose any order.

What you may find very useful is a [sortedcontainers.sorteddict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html):

> A SortedDict provides the same methods as a dict. Additionally, a SortedDict efficiently maintains its keys in sorted order. Consequently, the keys method will return the keys in sorted order, the popitem method will remove the item with the highest key, etc.
>
> An optional key argument defines a callable that, like the key argument to Python’s sorted function, extracts a comparison key from each dict key. If no function is specified, the default compares the dict keys directly. The key argument must be provided as a positional argument and must come before all other arguments.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 3], [2, 5, 6], [2, 1, 3]]
d = SortedDict()
for sub in l:
    k = sub[0]
    if k not in d or sub[1] < d[k][1]:
        d[k] = sub


print(list(d.values()))
```

It has all the methods you want [bisect](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.d.bisect), [bisect_left](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.d.bisect_left) etc..

Comment: Thanks, your answer has set me off in the right direction and the info on sortedcontainers is useful as well. On calling sorted twice: since the first sort is reversed and the second normal, I'm pretty sure two calls are required. That is, you can't specify separate ordering for different keys in one call.

Comment: @Aaron, you can actually do it in one using a lambda, I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, the solution might be like this:

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [7, 3, 6], [7, 1, 8]]

ordering = []
newdata = {}

for a, b, c in mylist:
    if a in newdata:
        if b < newdata[a][1]:
            newdata[a] = [a, b, c]
    else:
        newdata[a] = [a, b, c]
        ordering.append(a)

newlist = [newdata[v] for v in ordering]
```

So in `newlist` we will receive reduced list of `[[1, 2, 3], [7, 1, 8]]`.

Comment: Why would you use a list  when you are storing the keys in the dict?

Comment: I did not do measurements, but I think that `list` may work faster than `OrderedDict`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176513/ordereddict-performance-compared-to-deque

Comment: On the other hand, looking for element would be faster in dict's keys, thanks for the idea, will change the code a bit

Comment: a dict lookup is O(1) a list scan is O(n), you already have all the keys to do the lookup, if its in the dict it's in the list

Comment: Now it does not matter as it should be a list in the output.

Comment: I do not do lookups in a list anymore. `ordering` is an add-only list and it is used to keep the order of elements. It is iterated only once. Look on the implementation of OrderedDict in python - I am not sure it faster.

Comment: But I do not do list lookups anymore. I keep ordering of the keys in a list and store the data in a dict by key. So 'it does not matter' means that O(n) from your comment is no more applicable. I do dict lookups.

Comment: Here are some measurements about OrderedDict's performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629682/ordereddict-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict