# Complexity of deleting a key from python ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Deleting a key from a python `dict` or `defaultdict` in python is O(1) operation, [as mentioned here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~brgallar/week8_2.html) and [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). To remove a key from `OrderedDict`, we can either use `del d[key]` or use `popitem()` method, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem).

What is the underlying implementation of `OrderedDict` and the time complexity of `del` operation?

Edit: This answer [OrderedDict performance (compared to deque)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176513/ordereddict-performance-compared-to-deque) , refers to the complexity of `del` in `OrderedDict` as being O(1). However, how can we justify it at implementation detail level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OrderedDict performance (compared to deque)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176513/ordereddict-performance-compared-to-deque). While the questions are different, the answer there also answers your question.

Comment: Edited to include how it differs, and what detail I am looking for, which I could not find.

Comment: The `OrderedDict` class is implemented in Python (on top of a normal `dict`), so you can [go directly to the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fc46979b8c802675ca7fd51c6f2108a305001c8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L81) to see how it's implemented. The order is maintained by a doubly linked list. The link for any key can be efficiently looked up in a normal dict.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L129) of `OrderedDict.__delitem__` in Python 3.7 is as follows:

```
def __delitem__(self, key, dict_delitem=dict.__delitem__):
    'od.__delitem__(y) <==> del od[y]'
    # Deleting an existing item uses self.__map to find the link which gets
    # removed by updating the links in the predecessor and successor nodes.
    dict_delitem(self, key)
    link = self.__map.pop(key)
    link_prev = link.prev
    link_next = link.next
    link_prev.next = link_next
    link_next.prev = link_prev
    link.prev = None
    link.next = None
```

This code does 3 things:

- Remove an item from the internal key-value dictionary.
- Remove a node from the dictionary holding linked list nodes.
- Delete an item from a doubly linked list.

Since the average case complexity of all the above operations is constant, the average case complexity of `OrderedDict.__delitem__` is constant as well.

Do note however that the worst case complexity of deleting a key from a dictionary is `O(n)`, so the same applies for ordered dictionaries as well.

Comment: Has a lot in common with an LRU.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Indeed, I am doing the LRU question on Leetcode and I used the order-preserving feature of dictionary (in 3.6+) and it passed. It had a large time complexity though (beats 5% submissions), and I was wondering why. I used pure insertion and deletion for dict which is supposed to take amortized O(1). I started to check for implementation details of dict in 3.6+ for order-preserving and found this post, although this seems to refer to `OrderedDict` rather than the default dict.