# Time Complexity of finding the first item in a dictionary in Python 3.7+

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, python-3.7

Since Python 3.7, dictionaries preserve order based on insertion.

It seems like you can get the first item in a dictionary using `next(iter(my_dict))`?

My question is around the Big O time complexity of that operation?

Can I regard `next(iter(my_dict))` as a constant time (O(1)) operation? Or what's the best way to retrieve the first item in the dictionary in constant time?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm hoping to use this for coding interviews, where there's a significant emphasis on the time complexity of your solution, rather than how fast it runs in milliseconds.

Comment: @rdas As of Python 3.7 it's no longer just an implementation detail. Dictionary order is guaranteed to be in insertion order and it's a language feature. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

I think using an Ordered Dictionary is a valid data structure to use in an interview? No?

Comment: Look this isn't really relevant to my question. During algorithmic coding interviews, you typically present several solutions (and discuss tradeoffs), so I'd like to use Python 3.7+'s Ordered Dictionaries as ONE of my solutions. Therefore, I'd like to know how to get the first element in constant time complexity. It's not the only solution that I'll be presenting to the interviewer, so the question of whether "that's the answer my interviewer is looking for" is irrelevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complexity of deleting a key from python ordered dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800639/complexity-of-deleting-a-key-from-python-ordered-dict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the best way (actually you're getting the first key now, `next(iter(d.values()))` gets your value).

This operation (any iteration through `keys`, `values` or `items` for combined tables at least) [iterates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d53d8756f0403eec6a4e12f183103d651bed6c5/Objects/dictobject.c#L3639) through an array holding the [dictionary entries](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d53d8756f0403eec6a4e12f183103d651bed6c5/Objects/dict-common.h#L9):

```
PyDictKeyEntry *entry_ptr = &DK_ENTRIES(k)[i];
while (i < n && entry_ptr->me_value == NULL) {
    entry_ptr++;
    i++;
}
```

`entry_ptr->me_value` holds the value for each respective key.

If your dictionary is freshly created, this finds the first inserted item during the first iteration (the dictionary entries array is append-only, hence preserving order).

If your dictionary has been altered (you've deleted many of the items) this might, in the worse case, result in O(N) to find the first (among remaining items) inserted item (where N is the total number of original items). This is due to dictionaries not resizing when items are removed and, as a result, `entry_ptr->me_value` being `NULL` for many entries.

Note that this is CPython specific. I'm not aware of how other implementations of Python implement this.